# Difficulty setting up SSRS on new SQL Instance

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I've created a new SQL instance on a failover cluster node.  I set up Reporting services, and started designing a report.  The report calls a stored procedure on the DB.  I get this error when I try to run the run the report:

```
Index 'UNIQ_SnapshotChunkMapping' on table 'SegmentedChunk' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist.
```

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [FET]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[rptStoreReport]    Script Date: 1/11/2018 9:26:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptStoreReport] 
@StoreID int

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT StoreID, StoreType, State, CaseNumber, System, RiskType, 
        Ceiling, Height, ExistingSCOLanes, ExistingMannedLanes, ExistingReuseCams, 
        GMSCOQty, GMBeltQty, GRCSCOQty, GRCBeltQty, MannedQty, Notes FROM dbo.Stores 
        WHERE StoreID = ' + CAST(@StoreID as varchar) + ' AND DeletedDate = NULL'

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Comment: please add code to the question

Comment: That doesn't look like it corresponds to the error you are getting. That `SegmentedChunk` table is in the `ReportServer` database and that index does exist on that table in my db.

Comment: You are not forcing an index in the query above, it could be happening somewhere else, perhaps you have a trigger somewhere?

Comment: I agree with WEI_DBA. That looks like a ReportServer table.

Comment: Actually, it could be SSRS calling that behind the scenes. Check that table to make sure the index exists.

Comment: In the ReportServer DB, there is a SegmentedChunk table.  It is also in the ReportServerTempDB.  However, UNIQ_SnapshotChunkMapping does not exist on the table.

Comment: @DrewJackson Is there anything more detailed in the SSRS execution log?

Comment: There's actually nothing in any of the execution logs, almost like it wasn't even trying to run.